# How do I copy `<div contentEditable="true">` to `<textarea>` without stripping it out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, copy

How do I copy `<div contentEditable="true">` to `<textarea>` without stripping out all the HTML source codes?

I want automatically copy all source codes written in an editable div without stripping them out when they are copied to the textarea.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function copyText() {
var output = document.getElementById("divtext").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("text").value = output;
}
</script>

<div id="divtext" contentEditable="true" onkeyup="copyText();" style="text-align:left; width: 499px; height: 230px;"></div>

<textarea name="text" id="text" rows="14" cols="54" wrap="soft"></textarea>
```

The codes work, they do copy from div to textarea, but they strip them out so what I think is needed is a way to replace the stripped out so to keep or preserve the text as it was written without having it stripped out.

How do I add that replace function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the .text() function.  It will not 'strip' the html.

```js
function copyText() {
 $("#text").val($("#divtext").text());
}
```

```css
div, textarea {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divtext" contentEditable="true" onkeyup="copyText();" style="text-align:left; width: 499px; height: 230px;"></div>

<textarea name="text" id="text" rows="14" cols="54" wrap="soft"></textarea>
```

.

Comment: Thank you it worked. But I do have one question. How do I do so that the source code does not come out colored in the div? Because my div background I use is transparent black and the colors really destroys the design. If there is no way then I guess I will change the background of the div box, that is not a big deal.

Comment: I'm having a really hard time understanding that question.  You may want to post a new question or try to rephrase.

Comment: Forget that question, that part is not so important.

Comment: As long as you understood the main question I asked and you answered too that is what matters,

Comment: There is one problem though. I see that every time I have a line break the line breack is not copied. How do I fix that?

Comment: Huh, I'll look at that.

Comment: Well I tested it and all works fine until you push "Enter" and the line break is not copied. I am sure there must be something one can add to make that work. I am searching and I am looking into a solution too. If we both are looking then we might find the solution faster.

Comment: What I did was, whenever uses <br /> it will force a line break.

Comment: That is the problem, It should force a line break when using enter that way having an exact copy in textarea of the written in div.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery

```
$( ".hello" ).clone().appendTo( ".goodbye" );
```

In javascript, read this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

P/S: Use google searching before ask question please.

Comment: You did not answer to the question. Actually I think you did not even understand the question.

Comment: I did google it a loot and I found no direct answer. As I said the code I made works, but it also stripped out the text. So what I need to do is to not strip it out meaning it needs to for example replace this &gt; back to this >.
Because when copying right now I get everything stripped out.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstood. When using paste by right click, your code is not working. Is that your problem? I mean another problem :|